# Web scraping for rottentomatoes got error

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** a page from [rottentomatoes](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/).

The page screenshot is

[image]

As per the picture `span class= descriptor` is the parent class of `a class` and `div class = info director` is the gradparent of `Directed By`.

I want to **scrape** the directors' names

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
url= 'https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
director = []
people1 = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'info director'})
for d in people1:
    Dir = d.find('a').text
    director.append(Dir)
```

I got this error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Please include the tag of the language you are using to do your scraping. The code shown is neither HTML nor CSS.

Comment: Okay. I am using Python.

Comment: I think you mean ‘scrape’. To scrap means to throw away.

Answer (score 0):

targets the div with the class 'info director' and dumps all the href text into a list using a one liner

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
url = 'https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
directors = [a.text for a in (d.find('a') for d in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info director'})) if a]
for x in range(len(directors)):
    print(directors[x])  # output directors

# alternative loop
directors = []
for d in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info director'}):
    for a in d.find('a'):
        directors.append(a)
        print(a)
```

Comment: Here you did not use the span class= descriptor. However, `a` is under span and div tag. What is `a for a`?

Comment: I did not use the span because you are targeting the a href tag which is not a child of the span. That's also why you are receiving the error to begin with, because you are saying find all a tag child of span, which is none.

Comment: a for a is just to accomplish everything in a one-liner. It is a nested loop. The inner loop is finding all span tags with class "info director" and the outer loop is finding the a tags.

Comment: So the tag is the child of `div class = info director`. If I find `a` within `info director` I was getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please change the one linear with simple loops?

Comment: oops I updated my answer. the a for a should be a.text for a

Comment: As long as I understand you try to write down something like `people1 = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'info director'})`   `for d in people1:
  Dir = d.find('a').text`  `director.append(Dir)`   But it was not working with the same error.

Comment: See my updated answer. Both versions will output the list of directors, but the original does it in one line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229485/discussion-between-mr-mooo-cow-and-saswati).